# Adobe Illustrator Logo dispersion effect | In a circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

I am working on a sample project where I want to design a logo which should look like a letter "C" letter combined with Letter "O" but the letter C should be comining with letter C such that it should make a dispersion effect when connecting with O.

To be more precise I add that there's wanted no material movement impression. I want to blend the "C" tail which are 3 vector lines connecting with "O" starting with (Dispersion effect ) with a static bridge in such a way that they should not feel like they are separate letters. The C tail should directly go into the O but with a glass breaking (Dispersion) effect in contact.

**Approach I used**: Custom mini squares(***THIS IS THE POINT, I NEED EFFECT IN SQUARAS AND NOT IN CIRCLES***) and placed them manually in a circle such that they should be forming the circle.

Is there any better and non-destructive approach which i can use to acheieve the same effect?

My Work.

[image]

Kindly, guide.
Good day.

Comment: Can you draw on paper what you need the effect to finally be? But yeah sounds like you dont know how to use the rotate tool and translate effect. Anyway using illsutrator is really about destructive edits so expecting nondestructive edts to work is a bit edge case.

Comment: I want  to blend the "C" tail which are 3 vector lines connecting with "O" starting with (Dispersion effect ) in such a way that they should not feel like they are seperate letters or joined just magically. The C tail should directly go into the O keeping the glass breaking(Dispersion) effect in contact.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question. So, you don't know how to achieve the results?

Comment: I think you need to rethink the basic geometry of how a C could link to an O. Maybe explore that first, because it doesn't really work in your example.

Comment: I have run out of ideas. If you can do any help then kindly do let me know.

Comment: *Could* possibly use the [Polar Grid Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFJie.png) and then just remove anything unnecessary.